# System.Reflection.MethodInfo.Invoke and multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, reflection, methodinfo

Hi how do i call System.Reflection.MethodInfo.Invoke() with paramters with threads.

For instance..

Say I have a method that allows you to pass in a string that represents a
class name and calls corresponding class method dynamically , now i want to 
call this Methodinfo.invoke with threads ,I have no idea how to do this since i am calling invoke with paramter . Code snippet given meblow . Thank you for your help

```
Type classType = objAssembly.GetType("MyClassName");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType)
bject[] _objval = new object[3]; 
object[] parameters = new object[] { _objval };
MethodInfo mi = classType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
mi.Invoke(obj, parameters);  // <---**How do i call this with threads.. ????**
```

Comment: Do you want to make the cross-thread call to a UI thread, a threadpool thread, or a new worker thread?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Comment: hey i am new to C# and learning it everyday . I have very less idea on threads . Ususally i call thread like Thread t = new Thread(pts); t.Start(); . Similarly i want to call this mi.invoke wit hthreads . Hope you understand what i am telling

Comment: ok, that's a brand-new worker thread.  example coming...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're wanting to create a new thread with `System.Threading.Thread` rather than make the call on an existing UI thread or threadpool thread, first thing to notice is that with `System.Threading.Thread` you can use either a `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate.

You do want parameters to your thread's main method, but `ParameterizedThreadStart` only allows an `object`, which forces you to cast it to the required type.  So we'll just use a closure to get all the arguments passed across in a type-safe way.

```
public void InvokeOnNewThread(this MethodInfo mi, object target, params object[] parameters)
{
     ThreadStart threadMain = delegate () { mi.Invoke(target, parameters); };
     new System.Threading.Thread(threadMain).Start();
}
```

Example usage:

```
mi.InvokeOnNewThread(obj, parameters);
```

If you're working with .NET 2.0, then take out the keyword `this` from the parameter list and call like:

```
InvokeOnNewThread(mi, obj, parameters);
```

This will discard any return value, but so did the unthreaded example in your question.  If you need the return value leave a comment.

Comment: Thats perfect my dear friend . Thank you very much .can u explain me what ThreadStart threadMain = delegate () this does . Only  from last week i startedd using C# after beiong c++ programmer for 2 years . I know delegate is quite like function pointer ...

Comment: You already were using a delegate in your code: `new Thread(pts);`  But that delegate references a named method.  Here I am using an anonymous method, created with the `delegate` keyword, in order to capture variables.  This is a C# feature, not part of the .NET runtime.  The C# compiler will actually create a class (with a very weird name illegal to use in C# code) that stores the captured variables `mi`, `target`, and `parameters` and it will put the code in a method in that class.  Then when the method runs, it can read the parameters values using its `this` pointer.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you read Jon Skeet's introduction to closures here http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx  His book **C# in Depth** is also highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You can start a thread with an anonymous method:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(delegate() {
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClassName));

    object[] _objval = new object[3]; 
    object[] parameters = new object[] { _objval };
    MethodInfo mi = classType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
    mi.Invoke(obj, parameters); 
});
myThread.Start();
```

The code inside the `delegate() { ... }` is an anonymous method that is executed on the new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, why not use .Net 4.0 Framework it has an easier threading implementation.  Just use Parallel.For, Parallel.ForEach() or Parallel.Invoke().  Some further explanation here -> http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/parallel-programming-easier-than-ever-using-net-framework-4/

Comment: Since `Parallel.Invoke` accepts `Action` delegates which can't accept arguments, this doesn't really answer the question.  Letting the Parallel Tasks library manage a threadpool is a good alternative to `new Thread` of course, but the OP didn't seem to want to use a threadpool.