# Dynamic method inovcation in new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, reflection, dynamic

Can some give me hand here? I need this method to invoke the user's desired method in a new thread based on the user's choice from the main form. I think i am close, but I am stuck at how to pass in a variable the represents that user's choice of method in the new thread start.

heres my code

```
    public void GetTest()
    {
        _t = testListBox.SelectedIndex;

        if (_t < 0)
            return;

        _v = testListBox.SelectedValue;

        method = _v as MethodInfo;


        if (method == null)
            return;

        _selectedMethod = method.Name;

        MessageBox.Show(_selectedMethod.ToString());

        counter++;

        Thread UIthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(??????)); // this is will be a method based on the user's choice in the main form thread
        // adding Name of new Thread
        UIthread.Name = "UIThread";
        UIthread.Start();
        // Update test status
        _testStatus = "Running";
        //Make thread global
        _UIthread = UIthread;
    }
```

Comment: Is this a static method or some method on a class?  This is a question of reflection.  You need to resolve the concrete method and wrap that in an action that can be kicked off on a thread, or task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Reflection.MethodInfo.Invoke and multiple threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697596/system-reflection-methodinfo-invoke-and-multiple-threads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for all the help. Here's the answer for all the folks that care. You Create a thread start delegate. I found this out after reading these two posts: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/410294-using-reflection-multithreading http://www.pelennorfields.com/matt/2009/03/13/createdelegate-error-binding-to-target-method/

This method takes a reflected MethodInfo GetMethod listbox value and invokes the corresponding Instance method in a new thread. The thread is made global to allow the user to control the long-running method. The method is great because it allows for a dynamic class of instance methods, with out recompiling the entire program.code here

```
        public void GetTest()
    {
        _t = testListBox.SelectedIndex;

        if (_t < 0)
            return;

        _v = testListBox.SelectedValue;

        method = _v as MethodInfo;


        if (method == null)
            return;

        _selectedMethod = method.Name;

        MessageBox.Show(_selectedMethod.ToString());

        counter++;


        ThreadStart ts = (ThreadStart)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ThreadStart), this, method, true);

        Thread UIthread = new Thread(ts);
        UIthread.Start();
        _UIthread = UIthread; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadList();
    }

    private void LoadList()
    {
        lstTest.Items.Clear();
        var t1 = new MethodInfo
                     {
                         MethodName = "Test1", 
                         MethodToRun = this.Test1
                     };
        lstTest.Items.Add(t1);


        var t2 = new MethodInfo
                    {
                        MethodName = "Test2",
                        MethodToRun = this.Test2
                    };
        lstTest.Items.Add(t2);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = lstTest.SelectedItem as MethodInfo;
        if (t != null)
        {
            var a = new Task(t.MethodToRun);
            a.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Test1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test1 started");
    }

    private void Test2()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test2 started");
    }

}

public class MethodInfo
{
    public string MethodName;
    public Action MethodToRun;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return MethodName;
    }

}
```

Comment: That would work well, but I need the method to start in a new thread so I can synchronize GUI updates for a progress bar

Comment: It does start in a new thread. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: Name MethodInfo something else, creating a class with the same name as a framework class with a relatively similar purpose makes this code more confusing.

Comment: @ John Petrak - Thanks for posting the msdn article. I was unaware of this approach: "Creating and Running Tasks Implicitly." I will definitely give this a shot and get back to you with the results. One important question is however, is it possible to "pause" the task?i

Comment: @John Petrack, Also, this will be interesting to implement as the class that contains all the "test" methods is dynamic. Each class contains tests specific to a certain application. Eventually, I would like have my winform filter the "test" methods by application (class) using reflection. Ex: (JohnDeere Class, JDtest1 method), (Ford Class, FRtest1), etc. This going to be a challenge because I am learning as I go.

Comment: As far as I can tell, no pausing. You can cancel though.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a lamdba expression on your new thread.

I'm not sure if you are dealing with static or instance methods.  If your methods are static then you don't need to create an object instance:

```
method = _v as MethodInfo;
object[] parameters = null;

Thread UIthread = new Thread(() =>
{
    object obj = null;

    if (!method.IsStatic)
    {
        obj = Activator.CreateInstance(method.DeclaringType);
    }

    method.Invoke(obj, parameters);
});

UIthread.Start();
```

Comment: This looks good. Thanks! However I am still getting a null target exception when trying to execute.

Comment: @don_mega: If obj is null and the method is not static you **will** get a TargetException. It's hard to tell exactly what is going on without more information.

Comment: I'll post some more code from my project when I get back to my work computer tonight. I appreciate you working with and helping out. A lot of this coded is over my head, which I am try to rapidly learn :)